# How to print custom message in try catch - php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to write to log some data when exception occurred, since it is dynamic data and I need the message I tried with simple code, just to write 'Boom' if exception occurred.
However just the automatic exception data written in logs (as before the try catch).
can someone advise how to print to log in the catch?
I just need to add additional text to the exception, just to be more specific

```
try {
    $sheet->setCellValue($cell,$innervalue);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $message = 'Can not set value: '.$innervalue .' in cell ' .$cell .$headerArray[$headerIndex];
    \Log::info('boom');
}
```

and in the logs nothing displayed
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown on that line? It still looks like an uncatched exception.

Comment: This question isn't clear. Please provide more details.

Comment: yes the exception is in this line' I just want to print to logs. this is all the info I have, I want to print to logs text that I create just to add text to the logs in case of exception

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan make:Exception SomeAweSomeException
```

This way you have your own controle of how the exception should look and handle. Also you can use standards wich makes you code look cleaner.

```php
class SomeCustomException extends Exception
{
    // ...
 
    /**
     * Get the exception's context information.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function context()
    {
        return ['order_id' => $this->orderId];
    }
}
```

```php
use Exception;

class SetDeliverDateToFarAwayException extends Exception
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
            'Selecting more than three days into the future is not allowed'
        );
    }
}
```

and now my method wich creates the error message.

```php
    /**
     * Finalizes the scheduler
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws SetDeliverDateToFarAwayException|Throwable
     */
    public function set(): string
    {
        $today = Carbon::now();
        $deliver = new Carbon();
        $deliver->year($this->year ?? $today->year);
        $deliver->month($this->month ?? $today->month);
        $deliver->day($this->day ?? $today->day);
        $deliver->hour($this->hour ?? $today->hour);
        $deliver->minute($this->minute ?? $today->minute);

        #Mail gun can max schedule mail for 3 days in the future. So we throw an Exception if the date is to big.
        throw_if($deliver->diffInHours($today) > 72, new SetDeliverDateToFarAwayException());
        return Mail::schedule($deliver->toDateTimeString());
    }
```

Comment: I am not understand your answer, I want to print in the catch custom message. not fully understand

Comment: Well when creating a custom exception you can specify the message it prints out. I use it a lot for api calls so users get a message wich is more understandable. I can even translate if needed.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors

Comment: sorry I am new to laravel 7, is exists step by step instructions? since in the link it is very high level.  can I use also the original exception data? or I need to create everything?

Comment: just run the command line, create an Exception, and experiment a little.  I will add an example.

Comment: try {

    } catch(SomeCustomException $e) { 
        Log::info(json_encode($e->getMessage()));
    }

Comment: Sorry again I can not do it it is production in your code I am not seeing try catch.  and also can you pass to your exception the stack trace of the origin?

Answer (score 0):

this what worked for me

```
try {                      
                              $sheet->setCellValueExplicit('WELL DONE');
                              }
                              catch (\Exception $e) {
                                $errorMsg = 'the value of:\' '  .$innervalue . '\' in cell ' .  $cell .  ' in header: ' . $headerArray[$headerIndex] . 'problematic'  ;
                                \Log::error($errorMsg);
                                \Log::error($e->getMessage()); 
                                \Log::error($e->getTraceAsString());  
                                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
                              
                              }
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the exception log message use it like this -

```
    try {

    } catch(Exception $e) { 
        Log::info(json_encode($e->getMessage()));
    }
```

Comment: But I want custom message, I want to print my own text, I need it to be modified. I try to create csv with 600K cells, in the exception it says that one cell is wrong, so I want to print exactly which cell is wrong, since I can not check manually 600K data

Comment: As per the screenshot, it seems like you have a malformed object during CSV parsing. Try checking the data.

Comment: This is the problem, this is what I want to solve, this is the feature, the data is 600K rows and I want to display what is the wrong cell.

Comment: I think you can use `for-each` and display the each cells via `echo` and use `try-catch` it would actually stop on the  exact cell that trigger error but i doubt it would finish rendering before PHP reach runtime limit

Comment: I tried to print everything to the log, the server will crash in big files, and the user have latency since the logging takes time